# Google sheets - How to concat multiple values into multiple links

Tags: google-sheets

I am working with a google sheet that in one column can hold 1+ strings of numbers, and in another column, needs to read those numbers in and concat them with a link.

What I mean by this is and what works thus far: Column A - 324243324 || Column B - =concat("google.com/", Column A) = google.com/324243324

What I hope to get working: Column A - 324243324 5004938 || Column B - =concat("google.com/", Column A) = google.com/324243324 google.com/5004938

Is this possible? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to (a) split the input by spaces; (b) prepend each part by "google.com/"; and (c) join again, separated by spaces. This is achieved by

```
=join(" ", arrayformula("google.com/" & split(A1, " ")))
```

The `&` operator is equivalent to CONCAT but easier to type. `arrayformula` indicates that the operation is done on an array (the output of split).

However, these links will not be hyperlinked; joining makes them into plain text. To keep them functional, remove the last step, "join", so that each link appears in its own cell.